# node/js stop the function before running it again

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval

I have a function running at each time interval, I need to simply stop the function before running it again.

Something similar to the code below.

```
var interval = 1000*60*3.14159;

setInterval( function(){
  setTimeout( myfunction(), interval )
}, interval );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout` returns a `timeoutID` value that you can use later to stop the timer

```
var timeoutId = setTimeout( myfunction(), interval);
clearTimeout(timeoutId);
```

Comment: By executing the function directly, instead of passing a reference, the timeout is not respected and setTimeout has no effect. Removing this error leads to never executing the function, because the timeout is the same as the interval.

Comment: yeah, but that was just an example how you can clear the timeout you created

Answer (score 1):

Your code, especially together with the requirement, doesn't make sense. First, you need to pass a reference to a function to `setTimeout` instead of executing it directly,

```
setTimeout(myfunction, 1000);
```

Otherwise, setTimeout has no effect at all and the function will just be executed without a timeout.

Now if we fix this error, what we have is a interval that is the same for `setInterval` and for `setTimeout`. If you want to stop the execution of the function we've passed to `setTimeout` everytime the `setInterval` ticks, your `setTimeout` will be interrupted and never executed because of  the same interval you've specified. The next tick will stop the function before it did a thing.

See this example - notice that nothing happens:

```js
var interval = 1000;

setInterval( function(){
  var i = setTimeout( myfunction, interval )
  clearTimeout(i);
}, interval );

function myfunction() {
 console.log("you'll never see me"); 
}
```

Comment: but you can show me?  Because I can not make logic work.